# Why my code just writes the last variable?

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, matplotlib, video

The code below should make 10 videos with names 1,2,3,..., 10 but it just writes the last video and other videos are 0 kb. I am not sure where is the problem. The code is reproducible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=10
FPS=1
seconds = 100

load_x = np.random.rand(14,100,3)
coord = np.random.rand(5,2,10)


for i in range(num_geo):
    fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')
    video = VideoWriter((str(i) + ".mp4"), fourcc, FPS, (pixels, pixels))
    
for j in range(100):
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    a=load_x[0,j,:].tolist()
    a=matplotlib.colors.to_hex(a)

    plt.plot([coord[0][0][i], coord[4][0][i]], [coord[0][1][i], coord[4][1][i]], color=str(a), lw=8, antialiased=True)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
        
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
    data = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
    data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))   
 
    video.write(data)
video.release()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the second loop and all subsequent lines.

**EDIT**: you should probably pull a bunch of unnecessary calculations outside the second for loop as well. See updated version below:

```py
for i in range(num_geo):
    fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')
    video = VideoWriter((str(i) + ".mp4"), fourcc, FPS, (pixels, pixels))
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi, pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    for j in range(100):
        rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
        plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
        a=load_x[0,j,:].tolist()
    a=matplotlib.colors.to_hex(a)

    plt.plot([coord[0][0][i], coord[4][0][i]], [coord[0][1][i], coord[4][1][i]], color=str(a), lw=8, antialiased=True)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
            
    fig.canvas.draw()
        
    data = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
        data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))   
    
    video.write(data)
    video.release()
```

Comment: Thanks, It wrote on all videos but it overwrites line plt.plot after each iteration. Each video should have one color line but the second video has 2 colored lines, the third video has 3 colored lines and so on.

Comment: I am wondering how variable `i` in line `plt.plot` in the first iteration takes 1, in the second iteration just takes 2 not 1 and 2 and in the third iteration takes just 3, not 1,2 and 3.

Comment: If you can upvote or accept my answer, since I answered your original question, that'd be great!

Comment: The variable `i` is modified each time through the for loop. So it will only take on the values of 0,1,2,...,9. Never a combination of those integers.

Comment: The newly edited version might solve the other problems as well-specifically moving the line `fig = plt.figure(...)` outside the last for loop.

Comment: The revised code writes just one frame instead of 100. line `plt.plot` should be iterate 100 times for each video and each time takes a unique integer.